# Winforms Graphics flickering. (Double buffering doesn't help!)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, graphics, double-buffering

I'm trying to create a simple Windows Forms graphics app that basically will draw a circle every time the user clicks and it expands, while slowly fading away.

When I tried to use the `Paint()` Event for my graphics functionality, nothing happened, so I created a separate function called "Render" that is called in my main update `Timer`.

The app worked but the graphics flickered. After some researched I realized that I had to enable Double Buffering so that it would render to a buffer and then the buffer would be rendered to the screen.

The flickering still didn't stop!
Is this because double buffering only works for `Paint()` events and if so how do I get the `Paint()` event to work or am I not enabling Double Buffering right?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Widget
{

public class Circle
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Radius;
    public int Alpha;

    public Circle(float X, float Y, float Radius, int Alpha)
    {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.Radius = Radius;
        this.Alpha = Alpha;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static readonly int ScreenX = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    public static readonly int ScreenY = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

    public int WindowWidth = 500, WindowHeight = 500;
    public Graphics G;
    private Pen Pen;

    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private List<Circle> Circles;

    public Form1()
    {
        this.Text = "Widget - Sam Brandt";
        this.Size = new Size(WindowWidth, WindowHeight);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new Point(ScreenX - WindowWidth - 100, 0);
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.Icon = new Icon("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Code Repositories\\Visual Studios\\Widget\\Widget\\Properties\\WidgetIcon.ico");
        Pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        G = CreateGraphics();
        //this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnPaint);
        ConstructMouse();
        FormWithTimer();
        DoubleBuffered = true;

        Circles = new List<Circle>();
    }

    public void ConstructMouse()
    {
        this.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseUp);
        this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseMove);
        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseDown);
    }

    public void FormWithTimer()
    {
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = (10);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Circles.Add(new Circle(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y, 0, 255));
    }

   /*public void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        for (int i = 0; i < Circles.Count; i++)
        {
            Circle C = Circles[i];
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(C.Alpha, 0, 0, 0), 1), C.X - C.Radius, C.Y - C.Radius, 2 * C.Radius, 2 * C.Radius);
        }
    }*/

    private void Tick()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Circles.Count; i++)
        {
            Circle C = Circles[i];
            C.Radius++;
            C.Alpha -= 3;
            if (C.Alpha == 0)
            {
                Circles.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Render()
    {
        G.Clear(Color.White);
        for (int i = 0; i < Circles.Count; i++)
        {
            Circle C = Circles[i];
            G.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(C.Alpha, 0, 0, 0), 1), C.X - C.Radius, C.Y - C.Radius, 2 * C.Radius, 2 * C.Radius);
        }
    }

    public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Render();
        Tick();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you add double buffering?

Comment: why do you feel the need to use a timer?  a 10ms timer... that is why you flicker.

Comment: Philter Fernades: In the constructor. T McUnknown: How should I do it?

Comment: DoubleBuffered doesn't work on `G = CreateGraphics();`.  You have to use the paint event and redraw everything every time.

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - keep `DoubleBuffered = true` and use `Paint` event.

> When I tried to use a PaintEvent for my graphics functionality, nothing happened

When you do some modifications and want to reflect them, use [Control.Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which according to the documentation

> Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn.

In your case, something like this

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tick();
    Invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More observations here but probably will be the answer.

- Why Timer?
- Use the Paint event, it is called when the GDI+ determines it needs to, you are constantly painting with your code as-is.
- Your code makes it look like you are not using double buffering.

Comment: Thanks for replying! 1. I used a timer originally to enlarge the circles every 10 ms, but included the rendering because the paint event wasn't drawing. 2. When I use the Paint event nothing happens... Is that because I'm not double buffering correctly or something else? 3. I set the "DoubleBuffered" property to "true" in the constructor. Is there something else I need to do? Sorry I don't know, I'm new. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do all your drawing to a separate Graphics object, and then copy that to your main Graphics object on the timer tick event only if there's been a change. You may need to keep track of that with a boolean member. This means your background drawing will have to be triggered by some other event.

If your picture is actually changing every 10 milliseconds, I'd slow down the timer a bit and set it to 50 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in VB):

```
Dim aProp = GetType(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
aProp.SetValue(Me, True, Nothing)
```

Also had problems with double buffering, and usual setting property DoubleBuffered to true do not work. I have found this solution somewhere on web